# How to get vector embedding of (lat, long) points or GPS trajectories?

Tags: python, pandas, gps, geospatial, word-embedding

I have a data that consists of approx. 1.5M taxi trips. Each of these trips have it's GPS trajectory traveled along as a feature. I would like to embed these trajectories, which are lists of (lat, long) points and some points of the trajectories (like only the starting and ending point) as well.

I am looking for something like word2vec, glove, but for geographical domain. Until now, I have not found any benchmark method. My current code uses the library libpysal to retrieve weights from Kernel methods from my dataset, which defines trajectories as nodes and defines neighborhood based on the Gaussian kernel. Later I use node2vec to get vector embeddings.

```
from libpysal.weights import Kernel
import networkx as nx
w = Kernel.from_dataframe(dataset, fixed=False, function="gaussian")
nodes = w.weights.keys()
edges = [(node, neighbour) for node in nodes for neighbour in w[node]]
my_graph = nx.Graph(edges)

dimensions = 64
node2vec = Node2Vec(
    my_graph, dimensions=dimensions, walk_length=15, num_walks=100, workers=1
)
model = node2vec.fit(window=10, min_count=1, batch_words=4)
```

My dataset has the 'geometry' feature, which is a LineString object (for embedding trajectories), and later I save the embeddings like here:[image: trajectory and it's embedding] However, this method takes a lot of time and I am looking for something quicker.

Appreciate any tip!

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Could you add an example of what you have and what you expect? (just few points). We have geopandas, fiona, gdal, etc.

Comment: I have for each row of my dataset the trajectory that the taxi traveled along, that is list of latitude, longitude points looking like [(41.146254, -8.613972), (41.146479, -8.614476)..., (41.163048, -8.583984)]. I want to embed each of my trajectories into a vector, so that "similar" trajectories are embedded into similar vectors. Same for embedding (lat, long) points. The method should take (lat, long)_i and give vector v_i.

Comment: It is the second part that it is not clear: give us numbers of what do you expect (just few cases). (and edit your question to add information). "Vector" has many meaning, and many forms.

Comment: I'm assuming you want this for some machine learning task. I'm also looking for some nice way to represent lat/lon data et have done a bit of reading on the subject. There doesn't seem to be a consensus. The most useful approach I found was to project the lat/lon into a 2D rectangle, normalize the values into a unit square and work with that. You're going to lose some precision with the projection on a flat rectangle but given that you're working with taxi ride data, the rectangles should be fairly small so it shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: Yes, I want to later cluster my data based on these embeddings. Sounds interesting, thank you for the response @gchapuis, do you by any chance have a reference to the method you are referring to? (Any papers using this method)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://towardsdatascience.com/leveraging-geolocation-data-for-machine-learning-essential-techniques-192ce3a969bc and specifically the two paragraphs about "Pre-processing geodata"

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/ might be better for this sort of question